# onchange dropdown is always going to one option

Tags: html, select, onchange

EDIT - I Imported a name with an apostrophe in it and it screwed up everything.

I am trying to execute a code when the dropdown is changed. It seems to mostly work, I just can only change the dropdown once and/or it automatically goes to 1 every time. Overall, I am trying to fill multiple inputs with random names/words depending on which number is selected.

Thanks for the help

```html
<html>
<body>

<select onchange="myFunction1();" id="number" >
<option value="1"> 1 </option>
<option value="2"> 2 </option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="name">

<script>

function myFunction1() {
    if (document.getElementById("number").value = "1") {
        document.getElementById("name").value =( getRandomNameBLK() );
        }
       else if (document.getElementById("number").value = "2") {
        document.getElementById("name").value =( getRandomNameBLK2() );
        }
        
        }
         
        
        
        function getRandomNameBLK()
{
 var names = [
'1111cdcwe',
'11111eere',
'11111323f'
];
 
 return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
}

  function getRandomNameBLK2()
{
 var names = [
'2222cdcwe',
'2222reere',
'22224323f'
];
 
 return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT - I Imported a name with an apostrophe in it and it screwed up everything.

Comment: Take a look at using yoda conditions - https://stellarbluetechnologies.com/2017/06/yoda-conditions/. `"1" = document.getElementById("number").value` would have thrown an error and helped you diagnose this.

Comment: Ill check it out

Answer (score 1):

You have to use == to check equal condition

```
function myFunction1() { if (document.getElementById("number").value == "1") { document.getElementById("name").value =( getRandomNameBLK() ); } else if (document.getElementById("number").value == "2") { document.getElementById("name").value =( getRandomNameBLK2() ); } }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: What about the other =s?  They dont need to be doubled? I looked at my original code and it is set up as ==.

Comment: Since other =s not logical expression, they dont need to be ==